# How to optimize this code for speed, in F# and also why is a part executed twice?

Tags: optimization, f#

The code is used to pack historical financial data in 16 bytes:

```
type PackedCandle =
    struct
        val H: single
        val L: single
        val C: single
        val V: int
    end
    new(h: single, l: single, c: single, v: int) = { H = h; L = l; C = c; V = v }
    member this.ToByteArray =
        let a = Array.create 16 (byte 0)
        let h = BitConverter.GetBytes(this.H)
        let l = BitConverter.GetBytes(this.L)
        let c = BitConverter.GetBytes(this.C)
        let v = BitConverter.GetBytes(this.V)
        a.[00] <- h.[0]; a.[01] <- h.[1]; a.[02] <- h.[2]; a.[03] <- h.[3]
        a.[04] <- l.[0]; a.[05] <- l.[1]; a.[06] <- l.[2]; a.[07] <- l.[3]
        a.[08] <- c.[0]; a.[09] <- c.[1]; a.[10] <- c.[2]; a.[11] <- c.[3]
        a.[12] <- v.[0]; a.[13] <- v.[1]; a.[14] <- v.[2]; a.[15] <- v.[3]
        printfn "!!" <- for the second part of the question
        a
```

Arrays of these are sent across the network, so I need the data to be as small as possible, but since this is tracking about 80 tradable instruments at the same time, performance matters as well.
A tradeoff was made where clients are not getting historical data and then updates, but just getting chunks of the last 3 days minute by minute, resulting in the same data being sent over and over to simplify the client logic.. and I inherit the problem of making the inefficient design.. as efficient as possible. This is also done over rest polling which I'm converting to sockets right now to keep everything binary.

So my first question is:
how can I make this faster? in C where you can cast anything into anything, I can just take a float and write it straight into the array so there is nothing faster, but in F# it looks like I need to jump through hoops, getting the bytes and then copying them one by one instead of 4 by 4, etc. Is there a better way?

My second question is that since this was to be evaluated once, I made ToByteArray a property. I'm doing some test with random values in Jupyter Notebook but then I see that:

[image]

the property seems to be executed twice (indicated by the two "!!" lines). Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have array to write to (generally you should use buffer for reading & writing when working with sockets), you can use [`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.As<TFrom, TTo>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.as) to cast memory from one type to another (same thing that you can do with C/C++)

```ml
type PackedCandle =
    // omitting fields & consructor
    override c.ToString() = $"%f{c.H} %f{c.L} %f{c.C} %d{c.V}" // debug purpose

    static member ReadFrom(array: byte[], offset) =
        // get managed(!) pointer
        // cast pointer to another type
        // same as *(PackedCandle*)(&array[offset]) but safe from GC
        Unsafe.As<byte, PackedCandle> &array.[offset]

    member c.WriteTo(array: byte[], offset: int) =
        Unsafe.As<byte, PackedCandle> &array.[offset] <- c
```

Usage

```ml
let byteArray = Array.zeroCreate<byte> 100 // assume array come from different function

// writing
let mutable offset = 0
for i = 0 to 5 do
    let candle = PackedCandle(float32 i, float32 i, float32 i, i)
    candle.WriteTo(byteArray, offset)
    offset <- offset + Unsafe.SizeOf<PackedCandle>() // "increment pointer"

// reading
let mutable offset = 0
for i = 0 to 5 do
    let candle = PackedCandle.ReadFrom(byteArray, offset)
    printfn "%O" candle
    offset <- offset + Unsafe.SizeOf<PackedCandle>()
```

But do you really want to mess with pointers (even managed)? Have measured that this code is bottleneck?

##### Update

It's better to use [`MemoryMarshal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal) instead of raw `Unsafe` because first checks out-of-range and enforces usage of *unmanaged* (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/constraints) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/unmanaged-types)) types at runtime

```ml
member c.WriteTo (array: byte[], offset: int) =
    MemoryMarshal.Write(array.AsSpan(offset), &Unsafe.AsRef(&c))

static member ReadFrom (array: byte[], offset: int) =
    MemoryMarshal.Read<PackedCandle>(ReadOnlySpan(array).Slice(offset))
```

Comment: this could definitely work, I will test it and report. Yes, this is a bottle neck because a bunch of data gets assembled and then sent out; the process is done roughly 80 times at the end of a minute and all the data should ideally be sent at the same time; the shorter the processing the better it is

Comment: Unsafe.SizeOf<PackedCandle>() is returning 8 vs. 16; I have no clue why, it's 3 singles + 1 int, so it should be (3+1) * 4

Comment: @Thomas, weird. I've tested it locally on net5, sdk 5.0.7 and it works. You can apply StructLayout attribute and specify size manually

Comment: error was on my side; I'll be testing your solution later tonight and report here

Answer (score 4):

My first question would be, why do you need the `ToByteArray` operation? In the comments, you say that you are sending arrays of these values over network, so I assume you plan to convert the data to a byte array so that you can write it to network stream.

I think it would be more efficient (and easier) to instead have a method that takes a `StreamWriter` and writes the data to the stream directly:

```
type PackedCandle =
  struct
      val H: single
      val L: single
      val C: single
      val V: int
  end
  new(h: single, l: single, c: single, v: int) = { H = h; L = l; C = c; V = v }
  member this.WriteTo(sw:StreamWriter) =
      sw.Write(this.H)
      sw.Write(this.L)
      sw.Write(this.C)
      sw.Write(this.V)
```

If you now have some code for the network communication, that will expose a stream and you'll need to write to that stream. Assuming this is `stream`, you can do just:

```
use writer = new StreamWriter(stream)
for a in packedCandles do a.WriteTo(writer)
```

Regarding your second question, I think this cannot be answered without a more complete code sample.

Comment: I'm planning on sending the data through a Suave socket and I don't think I can get the stream there (I've an open question, that is not directly related to this, but my suave test code is posted there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68171103/streaming-data-from-events-to-a-suave-socket)

Comment: If you still need to produce a byte array, you can do this by using `MemoryStream` on the side that is calling the `WriteTo` operation.